# Asp.net login page- can't log in using PasswordSignInAsync

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor, blazor-server-side

I have tried to create my own login page in Blazor application. There is an option to use default register/login pages, but decided to make them a Blazor components.

The problem is that when I try to log in, the method PasswordSignInAsync() just starts to run and nothing happens. There is no exception, no warning, no error message. I always put a breakpoint on a subsequent method, but it never gets hit, no matter how long I wait. My code:

Index.razor

```
@page "/"
@using  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@inject SignInManager<IdentityUser> Manager
@inject UserManager<IdentityUser> UserManager

@if (!IsLoginSuccessful)
{
    <div>
        <input type="text" @bind-value="@Email" />
        <input type="password" @bind-value="@Password" />

        <button @onclick="@PerformLogin">LogIn</button>
    </div>
}
else
{
    <p>You have successfully logged in!</p>
}


@code {
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public bool IsLoginSuccessful { get; set; } = false;

    public async Task PerformLogin()
    {
        var user = await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(Email);
        var check = await Manager.CheckPasswordSignInAsync(user, Password, false);
        var result = await Manager.PasswordSignInAsync(Email, Password, false, false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            IsLoginSuccessful = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
       public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
            services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = false)
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

            services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
            {
                // Password settings.
                options.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 1;

                // Lockout settings.
                options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
                options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
                options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

                // User settings.
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters =
                "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789-._@+";
                options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = false;
            });

            services.AddRazorPages();
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
            services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider, RevalidatingIdentityAuthenticationStateProvider<IdentityUser>>();
(... my other DI methods)
```

Is there any way to determine why this task is never completed? When I use these default views, the login process goes smoothly, so I guess it has nothing to do with password hashing or email/username 
form.

The only moment this task was actually completed (and failed) was when I replaced the 'Email' parameter with the whole 'user' object.

EDIT: I managed to retrieve this error from the browser console:

```
Error: System.InvalidOperationException: The response headers cannot be modified because the response has already started.
(...)
```

I still have no idea why does this appear, since no process is run to modify the headers.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SignInManager won't work in razor pages, 
You have to write your login code (and all the other pages that needs to work with SignInManager ,e.g, ChangePassword, LogOut) in a .cshtml page instead of .razor

Then you can redirect to your root blazor page

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. I have created blazor project with authentication template from VS. I didn't like cshtml pages in my blazor app. Since blazor wasm is a SPA framework, you can easily call API written in your preferred language.

For example, I have used .net core API with JWT authentication. This approach is easy to implement and anytime you can switch back-end framework. 
Link below may help.

[blazorboilerplate](https://github.com/enkodellc/blazorboilerplate)

[additional_resources](https://github.com/AdrienTorris/awesome-blazor)